# Metro has encountered an error: While trying to resolve/build module '@react-native/normalize-color'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, metro-bundler

error: Error: While trying to resolve module `@react-native/normalize-color` from file `/Users/XXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/node_modules/deprecated-react-native-prop-types/DeprecatedColorPropType.js`, the package `/Users/XXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/node_modules/@react-native/normalize-color/package.json` was successfully found. However, this package itself specifies a `main` module field that could not be resolved (`/Users/XXXXX/XXXXX/XXXXX/node_modules/@react-native/normalize-color/index`. Indeed, none of these files exist:

Comment: did you solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i @react-native/normalize-color --force
```